# How is the colloquial "I don't miss those days" commonly expressed in German?

Tags: expression, colloquial

In conversation, I just said jokingly:

> Ja, den schlafmangelerfüllten Assistenzarzt-Tagen **weine** ich **keine Träne nach**. Wir waren immer kurz davor, sogar im Dienst stehend einzuschlafen...

Essentially, I wanted to express the idea of:

- *I **don't miss** those fighting-sleepiness-full-time resident-days when we were always a step away from falling asleep... standing up no less!*

"*I don't miss X*" – said with a sense of relief that something unpleasant is over and done with for you, once and for all.

I'm wondering if my phrasing,  though not a literal rendering, gets across the meaning well enough? How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed colloquially in German?

Comment: I think it's perfect. Did you receive any feedback during said conversation that made you believe people wouldn't get the meaning? Or is there any other reason why you're doubting?

Comment: @Arsak Hi. Oh, it's not that. As someone who hasn't systematically learnt German at university or anything, I got into the habit of mentally going through what I said and heard in conversation later to brush up on my spontaneous speaking skills with the benefit of hindsight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say "[Diesen Tagen] weine ich keine Träne nach" is perfectly fine. There are other possibilities, but this one is, in my opinion, possible even in colloquial speech. Perhaps not among youths today, but certainly among educated adults such as Assistenzärzte.

Other possibilities might be:

> - [Diese Zeiten] vermisse ich wirklich nicht
> - [Das] brauche ich echt nicht mehr
> - Bin ich froh, dass [das|diese Zeiten] vorbei ist/sind

But you should be careful regarding the sleepiness: your german sentence with "schläfrigkeiterfüllten" doesn't really express that you would **fight** the sleepiness. It might even convey the impression that you were lazy like a sloth (instead of an overworked Assistenzarzt)!

(Oh, and: it's ".. stehend einzuschlafen" not "... stehend zu einschlafen")

Comment: "Ich bin froh, dass das vorbei ist" strikes me as the only idiomatic phrase of the three

Comment: Thanks. Given the joking tone of my phrasing, should I have said something like: "*den **schlafmangelerfüllten** Assistenzarzt-Tagen*", contrasting "lacking" with "filled" as sort of a wordplay, as in "***hungererfüllten***"?

Comment: Yes, that would work, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't talk about *days* but rather about time:

> Ich vermisse diese Zeit(en) nicht, in der/denen wir als Assistenzärzte ...

Answer (score 2):

Though expressing the idea »I don't miss« correctly, the rather upper style idiom

> einer Sache keine Träne nachweinen

is rarely used in daily speech. A more colloquial way of expressing would use **»auf etwas [gern] verzichten können«** or **»gestohlen bleiben können«**.

> - Auf schläfrige Assistenzarzt-Tage, wie ich sie gehabt habe, kann ich
>     [gern] verzichten.
> - Schläfrige Assistenzarzt-Tage, wie ich sie gehabt habe, können mir gestohlen bleiben.

Answer (score 1):

Another proposal (which I consider as quite close to *don't miss*)

> Nach diesen Tagen .. sehne ich mich (wirklich) nicht zurück.

Answer (score 0):

"Ich erinnere mich nicht gerne daran [aber sehr gut]"